# input cascade could not be found/opened

Tags: c++, c, opencv

Guyss I need your help!!!. I am making my own haarcascade.xml file for vehicle detection using haartraining function in opencv . Anyway I stopped my training at 9th stage and following files created.

- params
- stage0
- stage1
- stage2
- .
- .
- .
- stage9

all these are xml files

Then i compiled convert_cascade.c in opencv sample folder and got the .exe file to get the final xml file from those created xml files files . Then I gave parameters like this in cmd (after entering the project folder)

convert_cascade --size="40x40" file_path_to_created xml files vehicle.xml

to that exe file and it says "input cascade could not be found/opened". I searched all over the internet but not found any working solution. Tell me how to solve this problem.

Note- I compiled convert_cascade.c(not in opencv derectory. in another directory) as c++ file in vs 2010 environment(opencv linked) and it built successfully.

My OS is windows 7.
opencv 2.4.8.
tell me if something unclear in my question. I will edit them

Comment: I think because it would be good to show code in your post

Comment: Maybe the code *require* the file names to end with `.xml`? Per your list, yours do not.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply .Up to now I have no code. I followed tutorial in "http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html#x15ebd98". And it says I must give the folder path of folder that contains created xml files(stage0,stage1,stage2..) and name of the xml file that is to be created. The program shows me how to enter parameters and tells "input cascade could not be found.."

Comment: @Jongware:     those stage xml files are located in folder named "data". So I gave the path to that folder. what u mean by "file names to end with .xml"?

Comment: I gave following command >convert_cascade --size="40x40" data vehicle.xml

Comment: convert_cascade --size="40x40" data\cascade.xml vehicle.xml

Answer (score 0):

it seems, you aborted the training (pressed Ctrl^c), thus the cascade.xml was not generated.

no worries, just restart your cmdline for the opencv_traincascade tool in the same way, and with the same args as  you did before, just with `-stage 9` . (maybe even 8, the last stage might be corrupted from the abort).

this should try to finish the training at the last stage, and generate a cascade.xml in the data folder.

then use that as argument to generate your vehicle.xml:

```
convert_cascade --size="40x40" data\cascade.xml vehicle.xml
```

Comment: both programs should allow this. just (maybe delete the last stage) and call it again.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply berak. Sorry I realized that my case is different. I used cascade training application for training. I set 40 stages there but stopped at 9th stage. I know as u mentioned cascade.xml will generate after 40 stages. (I know i should have set it to 20 or near). And I found that convert_cascade.exe will support only for files given by haartraining application instead of cascade training application. So I think this may be the reason convert_cascade gives me error. So i'm going to start training again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831111/opencv-traincascade-build-intermediate-result

Comment: by the way inside my data folder there is no cascade.xml file.. So wt is your opinion?