# cascade face detection C++ Opencv 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv3.0, cascade-classifier

I am trying to implement face detection mentioned in the tutorial

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier

I am using OpenCV 3.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I downloaed the cascade xml files from here

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades

When I compile the code it gives me this error message:

```
OpenCV Error: Parsing error (/...../haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml(5): Valid XML should start with '<?xml ...?>') in icvXMLParse, file /home/taleb/opencv3/opencv/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp, line 2220
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/taleb/opencv3/opencv/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp:2220: error: (-212) /home/taleb/pythonproject/test1/haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml(5): Valid XML should start with '<?xml ...?>' in function icvXMLParse
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What's in file haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml? Is it valid xml?

Answer (score 2):

I found a couple of fixes in stack overflow and other websites. They are as follows:

1. Change the character encoding from UTF-8 to ANSI with Notepad++.
2. Previous answer:

> convert_cascade is for cascades trained by haartraining application and it does not support a format of cascades trained by traincascade application.
>
> To do this with traincascade, just run opencv_traincascade again with
>   the same "-data" but set "-numStages" to the point you want to
>   generate up to. The application will load the trained stages, realize
>   that there is required number of stages, write the result cascade in
>   xml and finish a work. Interrupting the process during a stage could
>   result in corrupt data, so if you're best off deleting the stage in
>   completion.

refrence: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25831423/5671364.

3. XML Standard states:

> if no encoding declaration is present in the XML document (and no
>   external encoding  declaration mechanism such as the HTTP header is
>   available), the assumed encoding of an XML document depends on the
>   presence of the Byte-Order-Mark (BOM).

There are 3 ways to fix this:

- Let OpenCV just put the ´encoding="ASCII"´ tag into the top root XML
  tag.
- Leave the top root XML tag, but encode everything as UTF-8
  before writing it to file.
- Do something else, with Byte-Order-Mark,
  but keep it to the standard.

refrence: http://code.opencv.org/issues/976

Comment: Changing from UTF to ANSI in Notepad++ worked for me. Thx